# twitterscaper ScraperException

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
    import os
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://127.0.0.1:56916"
os.environ["https_proxy"] = "http://127.0.0.1:56916"
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
from transformers import pipeline
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
#抓取某一用户数据

# Creating list to append tweet data 
tweets_list1 = []

# Using TwitterSearchScraper to scrape data and append tweets to list
for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:QCompounding').get_items()): # CharlieMunger00 Mayhem4Markets QCompounding
    if i>20: #number of tweets you want to scrape
        break
    tweets_list1.append([tweet.date,  tweet.content, tweet.user.username, tweet.likeCount, tweet.user.displayname, tweet.lang,tweet.hashtags,tweet.mentionedUsers,tweet.inReplyToUser,tweet.quotedTweet,tweet.retweetedTweet,tweet.media])
    
# Creating a dataframe from the tweets list above
tweets_df1 = pd.DataFrame(tweets_list1, columns=['Datetime',  'Text', 'Username', 'Like Count', 'Display Name', 'Language','hashtags','mentionedUsers','inReplyToUser','quotedTweet','retweetedTweet','media'])

tf=tweets_df1[tweets_df1['inReplyToUser'].isnull()]

from urllib.request import urlretrieve
tf=tweets_df1[tweets_df1['media'].isnull()==False]
for i in range(tf.shape[0]):
    try:
        kk=str(i)+'i'
        urlretrieve(tf.iloc[i,-1][0].fullUrl, "d:/data/photo2/{}.jpg".format(kk))  
    except:
        continue
```

error happens:

```
File "e:\temp\ipykernel_16024\2936908550.py", line 14, in <cell line: 14>
    for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:QCompounding').get_items()): # CharlieMunger00 Mayhem4Markets QCompounding

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\twitter.py", line 680, in get_items
    for obj in self._iter_api_data('https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json', params, paginationParams, cursor = self._cursor):

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\twitter.py", line 369, in _iter_api_data
    obj = self._get_api_data(endpoint, reqParams)

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\twitter.py", line 338, in _get_api_data
    self._ensure_guest_token()

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\snscrape\modules\twitter.py", line 301, in _ensure_guest_token
    r = self._get(self._baseUrl if url is None else url, headers = {'User-Agent': self._userAgent}, responseOkCallback = self._check_guest_token_response)

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\snscrape\base.py", line 216, in _get
    return self._request('GET', *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\snscrape\base.py", line 212, in _request
    raise ScraperException(msg)

ScraperException: 4 requests to https://twitter.com/search?f=live&lang=en&q=from%3AQCompounding&src=spelling_expansion_revert_click failed, giving up.
```

it works well in 1years earlier ,so what happend to my same codes? the proxy is no problem.
it works well in 1years earlier ,so what happend to my same codes? the proxy is no problem.
it works well in 1years earlier ,so what happend to my same codes? the proxy is no problem.
it works well in 1years earlier ,so what happend to my same codes? the proxy is no problem.